# Assign Keyboard shortcut per application in Linux Desktop Environment

Tags: linux, autohotkey

I would like to inquire if there is a program in Linux that we can use to assign new keyboard shortcut per application. For example, if I'm in FeatherPad I would like to assign `Super+S` to save. If I'm in terminal, I would like to use `Super+V` to paste.

Or a program that cab map/assign new shortcut and translate that to an existing shortcut. If in terminal I can paste with `Shift+Insert` then I would like to map `Super+V` to `Shift+Insert`

The closest analogy would be a program like `Autohotkey` in Microsoft Windows. How do I do this in Linux Desktop environment regardless it is Gnome2/Unity/XFCE etc. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There used to be a way to do this called "custom accelerators" or "editable accelerators". It used to be supported in GNOME 2 and XFCE (maybe in others). But since the move to gtk3, this functionality [seems to have been removed](https://docs.xfce.org/faq#how_to_configure_shortcutshotkeysmenu_accelerators) in GTK-based desktop environments.

In KDE/Plasma, you can use System Settings -> Shortcuts -> Global Shortcuts and then the plus symbol to add specific shortcuts that only apply to certain applications, but unfortunately, not all applications support it.

In FeatherPad itself, there should be Options -> Preferences -> Shortcuts, but I've had no luck getting it to register any shortcut consisting of just Super and a key.

I'm unfamiliar with Autohotkey but it seems that [AutoKey](https://github.com/autokey/autokey) is sometimes mentioned as an alternative on Linux?

Comment: Thanks KDE has evolved further than I anticipated. The KDE solution works. I tried modifying the shortcut in MXLinux (XFCE4 desktop) using `xev` and `xmodmap` combination. The Super_L key works but not the Control_L key. The pain of controling Linux using MacOS VirtualBox.

Comment: Ah, with the macOS + VirtualBox information I also understand what your motivation for changing it was :)  Glad to hear it works, cheers!